my c++ app don't run after i add this code
I add this code to my C++ app but I can't run the app anymore:
void setclipbord(const char* szBuffer)
{
    OpenClipboard(NULL);

    HGLOBAL hClipboardData = GlobalAlloc(GMEM_MOVEABLE, strlen(szBuffer) + 1);
    char* pchData = (char*)GlobalLock(hClipboardData);
    strcpy(pchData, szBuffer);
    GlobalUnlock(hClipboardData);

    EmptyClipboard();
    SetClipboardData(CF_TEXT, hClipboardData);

    CloseClipboard();
}

I use the last version of Visual Studio 2022, and it reports 1 error and 2 warnings:

Warning   'hClipboardData' could be '0', and is a copy of the value found in 'GlobalAlloc()`169':  this does not adhere to the specification for the function 'GlobalLock'.


Warning   'pchData' could be '0':  this does not adhere to the specification for the function 'strcpy'.


Error 'strcpy': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using strcpy_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.

I use these libraries:
#include <iostream>   
#include <string>   
#include <windows.h>   
#include <winuser.h>   
#include <cstring>   
#include <time.h>


Do not tag C for C++ questions.

Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?.

Please [edit] your question to copy-paste your build-log as text.

"cant find any error but show 2warn" - the screenshot you posted actually contains 1 error (in the last line).

The IDE tries to be helpful and tell you that GlobalAlloc and GlobalLock both might fail and you don't check for that.

And for the last one, see How to use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

Do you mean "I can't compile the app" or "I can't run the app"? It sounds like you are dealing with a compiler error, and the program hasn't even tried to run yet

The warnings are there because you're ignoring errors -- if, let's say,GlobalAlloc fails it returns NULL, but that's not a valid input for GlobalLock. And just look up the strcpy_s -- it's basically a strcpy with an additional parameter indicating the length of the destination buffer, so it can avoid an overflow.

You need to define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS to use strcpy().
Just place the following line IN FRONT of your headers (if you place it behind the headers, it wont work):
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

So in the end, your headers should look like this:
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <iostream>   
#include <string>   
#include <windows.h>   
#include <winuser.h>   
#include <cstring>   
#include <time.h>


strcpy() cannot be implemented safely. It's one of the worst functions that exist in C's Standard Library. Proposing to silence the compiler (rather than using a safe alternative) is criminally negligent.

@IInspectable the only difference between strcpy() and strcpy_s() is that strcpy_s() checks whether the destination buffer has enough space for the string to be copied, and strcpy() does not. However, here, this is useless, because allocating wcslen() + 1 bytes (like the code does with GlobalAlloc()) ensures that the buffer is large enough to fit the string. (Only if the allocation succeeds, of course). Here, it would even be overhead, as you have to re-calculate the buffer size, even though you already know the string will fit, only for strcpy_s() to do a useless compare.

"However, here, this is useless" - It is not. If nothing else it serves as documentation, making it possible to immediately see whether the code is correct. Plus, if you look at the actual function signature in string.h you'll see loads of SAL annotations informing static code analysis. That alone leads to better, safer code. If you're only ever doing what is strictly necessary, you'll just be writing code too clever for your own good. We have half a century of data speaking a clear language regarding this topic.
